# Deck.GL How to adjust setstate correctly so that Scatterplotlayer and Tripslayer can render synchronously

Tags: javascript, reactjs, deck.gl

(1) In deck.gl, realize the visual effect after overlaying the two layers. The effect now achieved is that TripsLayer can be automatically rendered because of the addition of animate, but ScatterplotLayer can only achieve the animation effect by dragging the timeline progress bar below, as shown below. That is, after superposition, they now appear to be two unrelated layers. In ScatterplotLayer (with DataFilterExtension added), the radius of the circle is still controlled by the progress bar at the bottom of the screen. Drag to change the size instead of auto rendering similar to TripsLayer.

I want them to achieve simultaneous rendering based on the common attribute timestamp. In other words, when the trajectory of TripsLayer moves, the circle radius of ScatterplotLayer will also change accordingly. I also added animate in ScatterplotLayer before, but it has no effect, it may be that Setstate is not adjusted correctly. Thank you very much for your help ~~
Screenshot of the effect now achieved and the complete code is as follows:

```
import React, {Component, Fragment} from 'react';

import {render} from 'react-dom';

import {StaticMap} from 'react-map-gl';

import {AmbientLight, PointLight, LightingEffect} from '@deck.gl/core';

import DeckGL from '@deck.gl/react';

import {PolygonLayer} from '@deck.gl/layers';

import {TripsLayer} from '@deck.gl/geo-layers';

import {ScatterplotLayer} from '@deck.gl/layers';

import {DataFilterExtension} from '@deck.gl/extensions';

import {MapView} from '@deck.gl/core';

import RangeInput from './range-input';


// Set your mapbox token here

const MAPBOX_TOKEN = process.env.MapboxAccessToken; // eslint-disable-line


// Source data CSV

const DATA_URL1 = {

 TRIPS:

   './package1.json' // eslint-disable-line

};

const DATA_URL =

 './data2.csv'; // eslint-disable-line


const MAP_VIEW = new MapView({

   // 1 is the distance between the camera and the ground

   farZMultiplier: 100

 });


const ambientLight = new AmbientLight({

 color: [122, 122, 122],

 intensity: 1.0

});


const pointLight = new PointLight({

 color: [255, 255, 255],

 intensity: 2.0,

 position: [127.05, 37.5, 8000]

});


const lightingEffect = new LightingEffect({ambientLight, pointLight});


const material = {

 ambient: 0.1,

 diffuse: 0.6,

 shininess: 32,

 specularColor: [60, 64, 70]

};


const DEFAULT_THEME = {

 buildingColor: [74, 80, 87],

 trailColor0: [253, 128, 93],

 trailColor1: [23, 184, 190],

 material,

 effects: [lightingEffect]

};


const INITIAL_VIEW_STATE = {

 longitude: 126.9779692,

 latitude: 37.566535,

 zoom: 6,

 pitch: 0,

 bearing: 0

};


const landCover = [[[-74.0, 40.7], [-74.02, 40.7], [-74.02, 40.72], [-74.0, 40.72]]];


const MS_PER_DAY = 8.64e7; // milliseconds in a day


const dataFilter = new DataFilterExtension({filterSize: 1});


export default class App extends Component {

 constructor(props) {

   super(props);

   this.state1 = {

     time: 0

   };


   const timeRange = this._getTimeRange(props.data);


   this.state = {


     timeRange,

     filterValue: timeRange,

     hoveredObject: null,

   };

   this._onHover = this._onHover.bind(this);

   this._renderTooltip = this._renderTooltip.bind(this);

 }


 componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {

   if (nextProps.data !== this.props.data) {

     const timeRange = this._getTimeRange(nextProps.data);

     this.setState({timeRange, filterValue: timeRange});

   }

 }


 componentDidMount() {

   this._animate();

 }


 componentWillUnmount() {

   if (this._animationFrame) {

     window.cancelAnimationFrame(this._animationFrame);

   }

 }



 _animate() {

   const {

     loopLength = 1000, // unit corresponds to the timestamp in source data

     animationSpeed = 20 // unit time per second

   } = this.props;

   const timestamp = Date.now() / 1000;

   const loopTime = loopLength / animationSpeed;


   this.setState({

     time: ((timestamp % loopTime) / loopTime) * loopLength

   });

   this._animationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame(this._animate.bind(this));

 }


 _getTimeRange(data) {

   if (!data) {

     return null;

   }

   return data.reduce(

     (range, d) => {

       const t = d.timestamp / MS_PER_DAY;

       range[0] = Math.min(range[0], t);

       range[1] = Math.max(range[1], t);

       return range;

     },

     [Infinity, -Infinity]

   );

 }


 _onHover({x, y, object}) {

   this.setState({x, y, hoveredObject: object});

 }


 _renderLayers() {

   const {

     buildings = DATA_URL1.BUILDINGS,

     trips = DATA_URL1.TRIPS,

     trailLength = 30,

     theme = DEFAULT_THEME

   } = this.props;


   const {data} = this.props;

   const {filterValue} = this.state;



   return [

     data &&

     new ScatterplotLayer({

       id: 'earthquakes',

       data,

       opacity: 0.8,

       radiusScale: 1,

       radiusMinPixels: 1,

       wrapLongitude: true,


       getPosition: d => [d.longitude, d.latitude, -d.depth * 1000],

       getRadius: d => d.VisitingTime * 200,

       getFillColor: d => {

         const r = Math.sqrt(Math.max(d.depth, 0));

         return [255 - r * 15, r * 5, r * 10];

       },


       getFilterValue: d => d.timestamp / MS_PER_DAY, // in days

       filterRange: [filterValue[0], filterValue[1]],

       filterSoftRange: [

         filterValue[0] * 0.9 + filterValue[1] * 0.1,

         filterValue[0] * 0.1 + filterValue[1] * 0.9

       ],

       extensions: [dataFilter],


       pickable: true,

       onHover: this._onHover

     }),


     new PolygonLayer({

       id: 'ground',

       data: landCover,

       getPolygon: f => f,

       stroked: false,

       getFillColor: [0, 0, 0, 0]

     }),

     new TripsLayer({

       id: 'trips',

       data: trips,

       getPath: d => d.path,

       getTimestamps: d => d.timestamps,

       getColor: d => (d.vendor === 0 ? theme.trailColor0 : theme.trailColor1),

       opacity: 0.3,

       widthMinPixels: 2,

       rounded: true,

       trailLength,

       currentTime: this.state.time,


       shadowEnabled: false

     }),

     new PolygonLayer({

       id: 'buildings',

       data: buildings,

       extruded: true,

       wireframe: false,

       opacity: 0.5,

       getPolygon: f => f.polygon,

       getElevation: f => f.height,

       getFillColor: theme.buildingColor,

       material: theme.material

     })





   ];

 }


 _renderTooltip() {

   const {x, y, hoveredObject} = this.state;

   return (

     hoveredObject && (

       <div className="tooltip" style={{top: y, left: x}}>

         <div>

           <b>Time: </b>

           <span>{new Date(hoveredObject.timestamp).toUTCString()}</span>

         </div>

         <div>

           <b>VisitingTime: </b>

           <span>{hoveredObject.VisitingTime}</span>

         </div>

         <div>

           <b>Depth: </b>

           <span>{hoveredObject.depth} km</span>

         </div>

       </div>

     )

   );

 }


 _formatLabel(t) {

   const date = new Date(t * MS_PER_DAY);

   return `${date.getUTCFullYear()}/${date.getUTCMonth() + 1}`;

 }


 render() {

   const {

     viewState,

     mapStyle = 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v9',

     theme = DEFAULT_THEME

   } = this.props;

   const {timeRange, filterValue} = this.state;



   return (

     <Fragment>

     <DeckGL

     views={MAP_VIEW}

       layers={this._renderLayers()}

       effects={theme.effects}

       initialViewState={INITIAL_VIEW_STATE}

       viewState={viewState}

       controller={true}

     >

       <StaticMap

         reuseMaps

         mapStyle={mapStyle}

         preventStyleDiffing={true}

         mapboxApiAccessToken={MAPBOX_TOKEN}

       />

       {this._renderTooltip}


     </DeckGL>


     {timeRange && (

         <RangeInput

           min={timeRange[0]}

           max={timeRange[1]}

           value={filterValue}

           formatLabel={this._formatLabel}

           onChange={({value}) => this.setState({filterValue: value})}

         />

       )}

       </Fragment>

   );

 }

}


export function renderToDOM(container) {

 require('d3-request').csv(DATA_URL, (error, response) => {

   if (!error) {

     const data = response.map(row => ({

       timestamp: new Date(`${row.DateTime} UTC`).getTime(),

       latitude: Number(row.Latitude),

       longitude: Number(row.Longitude),

       depth: Number(row.Depth),

       VisitingTime: Number(row.VisitingTime)

     }));

     render(<App data={data} />, container);

   }

 });


}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eV7XL.png)

(2) The following code and screenshots are that I put setstate in setinterval and added a timer to implement a method called tick (). The timer component will call it every second. Did not move. You can see in the browser ’s developer tools that time is updated in real time, but filterValue is not updated (filterValue: Called to retrieve the value for each object that it will be filtered by. Returns either a number (if filterSize: 1) or an array. Here is filter by timestamp). There may be a small step that is not set correctly. Thank you very much for your advice ~

```
 import React, {Component, Fragment} from 'react';

import {render} from 'react-dom';

import {StaticMap} from 'react-map-gl';

import {AmbientLight, PointLight, LightingEffect} from '@deck.gl/core';

import DeckGL from '@deck.gl/react';

import {PolygonLayer} from '@deck.gl/layers';

import {TripsLayer} from '@deck.gl/geo-layers';

import {ScatterplotLayer} from '@deck.gl/layers';

import {DataFilterExtension} from '@deck.gl/extensions';

import {MapView} from '@deck.gl/core';



// Set your mapbox token here

const MAPBOX_TOKEN = process.env.MapboxAccessToken; // eslint-disable-line


// Source data CSV

const DATA_URL1 = {

 TRIPS:

   './package1.json' // eslint-disable-line

};

const DATA_URL =

 './data2.csv'; // eslint-disable-line


const MAP_VIEW = new MapView({

   // 1 is the distance between the camera and the ground

   farZMultiplier: 100

 });


const ambientLight = new AmbientLight({

 color: [122, 122, 122],

 intensity: 1.0

});


const pointLight = new PointLight({

 color: [255, 255, 255],

 intensity: 2.0,

 position: [127.05, 37.5, 8000]

});


const lightingEffect = new LightingEffect({ambientLight, pointLight});


const material = {

 ambient: 0.1,

 diffuse: 0.6,

 shininess: 32,

 specularColor: [60, 64, 70]

};


const DEFAULT_THEME = {

 buildingColor: [74, 80, 87],

 trailColor0: [253, 128, 93],

 trailColor1: [23, 184, 190],

 material,

 effects: [lightingEffect]

};


const INITIAL_VIEW_STATE = {

 longitude: 126.9779692,

 latitude: 37.566535,

 zoom: 6,

 pitch: 0,

 bearing: 0

};


const landCover = [[[-74.0, 40.7], [-74.02, 40.7], [-74.02, 40.72], [-74.0, 40.72]]];


const MS_PER_DAY = 8.64e7; // milliseconds in a day


const dataFilter = new DataFilterExtension({filterSize: 1});


export default class App extends Component {

 constructor(props) {

   super(props);

   this.state = {date: new Date()};


   const timeRange = this._getTimeRange(props.data);


   this.state = {

     timeRange,

     filterValue: timeRange,


   };


 }


 componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {

   if (nextProps.data !== this.props.data) {

     const timeRange = this._getTimeRange(nextProps.data);

     this.setState({timeRange, filterValue: timeRange});

   }

 }


 componentDidMount() {

   this._animate();

   this.timerID = setInterval(

     () => this.tick(),

     1000

     );

 }


 componentWillUnmount() {

   if (this._animationFrame) {

     window.cancelAnimationFrame(this._animationFrame);

     clearInterval(this.timerID);

   }

 }

 tick() {

   this.setState({

     date: new Date()

   });

 }



 _animate() {

   const {

     loopLength = 1000, // unit corresponds to the timestamp in source data

     animationSpeed = 20 // unit time per second

   } = this.props;

   const timestamp = Date.now() / 1000;

   const loopTime = loopLength / animationSpeed;


   this.setState({

     time: ((timestamp % loopTime) / loopTime) * loopLength

   });

   this._animationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame(this._animate.bind(this));

 }


 _getTimeRange(data) {

   if (!data) {

     return null;

   }

   return data.reduce(

     (range, d) => {

       const t = d.timestamp / MS_PER_DAY;

       range[0] = Math.min(range[0], t);

       range[1] = Math.max(range[1], t);

       return range;

     },

     [Infinity, -Infinity]

   );

 }




 _renderLayers() {

   const {

     buildings = DATA_URL1.BUILDINGS,

     trips = DATA_URL1.TRIPS,

     trailLength = 30,

     theme = DEFAULT_THEME

   } = this.props;


   const {data} = this.props;

   const {filterValue} = this.state;



   return [

     data &&

     new ScatterplotLayer({

       id: 'ScatterplotLayer',

       data,

       opacity: 0.8,

       radiusScale: 1,

       radiusMinPixels: 1,

       wrapLongitude: true,

       rounded: true,

       getTimestamps: d => d.timestamps,

       getPosition: d => [d.longitude, d.latitude],

       getRadius: d => d.VisitingTime * 200,

       getFillColor: d => {

         const r = Math.sqrt(Math.max(d.depth, 0));

         return [255 - r * 15, r * 5, r * 10];

       },


       getFilterValue: d => d.timestamp / MS_PER_DAY, // in days

       currentTime: this.state.time,

       filterRange: [filterValue[0], filterValue[1]],

       filterSoftRange: [

         filterValue[0] * 0.9 + filterValue[1] * 0.1,

         filterValue[0] * 0.1 + filterValue[1] * 0.9

       ],

       extensions: [dataFilter]



     }),


     new PolygonLayer({

       id: 'ground',

       data: landCover,

       getPolygon: f => f,

       stroked: false,

       getFillColor: [0, 0, 0, 0]

     }),

     new TripsLayer({

       id: 'trips',

       data: trips,

       getPath: d => d.path,

       getTimestamps: d => d.timestamps,

       getColor: d => (d.vendor === 0 ? theme.trailColor0 : theme.trailColor1),

       opacity: 0.3,

       widthMinPixels: 2,

       rounded: true,

       trailLength,

       currentTime: this.state.time,

       shadowEnabled: false

     }),

     new PolygonLayer({

       id: 'buildings',

       data: buildings,

       extruded: true,

       wireframe: false,

       opacity: 0.5,

       getPolygon: f => f.polygon,

       getElevation: f => f.height,

       getFillColor: theme.buildingColor,

       material: theme.material

     })





   ];

 }




 render() {

   const {

     viewState,

     mapStyle = 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v9',

     theme = DEFAULT_THEME

   } = this.props;




   return (

     <Fragment>

     <DeckGL

     views={MAP_VIEW}

       layers={this._renderLayers()}

       effects={theme.effects}

       initialViewState={INITIAL_VIEW_STATE}

       viewState={viewState}

       controller={true}

     >

       <StaticMap

         reuseMaps

         mapStyle={mapStyle}

         preventStyleDiffing={true}

         mapboxApiAccessToken={MAPBOX_TOKEN}

       />


     </DeckGL>


     </Fragment>


   );

 }

}


export function renderToDOM(container) {

 require('d3-request').csv(DATA_URL, (error, response) => {

   if (!error) {

     const data = response.map(row => ({

       timestamp: new Date(`${row.DateTime} UTC`).getTime(),

       latitude: Number(row.Latitude),

       longitude: Number(row.Longitude),

       depth: Number(row.Depth),

       VisitingTime: Number(row.VisitingTime)

     }));

     render(<App data={data} />, container);

   }

 });


}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0p476.png)

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm trying to do something similar.